# colorbox, show the gallery from arrays link

Tags: jquery, arrays, colorbox

I have gallery which i want to show in jquery colorbox,

the user clicks on the link and it opens the overlay gallery.the gallery containing 1 or more images.

```
<a href="" id="30">
<img border="0" src="/uploads/coverGallery1.png" width="225" height="164" alt="" class="image"/>
</a>
```

I can only deliver the images from db as array link:

```
<script>
   var prod_img_30 = Array(       // 30: is the id of the link
            Array('/uploads/image1.png',0),
            Array('/uploads/image2.png',0), 
            Array('/uploads/image1.png',0)
                    );
</script>
```

I need to integrate the jquery colorbox to my code but till now i couldn't, any idea would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

ColorBox only works with elements in the DOM, so you would have to temporarily add links to your document to be able to show these as a gallery.  For example:

```
var $gallery = $('<div>').hide().appendTo('body');
var arr = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'];

$.each(arr, function(i){
    $('<a href="'+arr[i]+'"></a>').appendTo($gallery);
});

$gallery.find('a').colorbox({rel:'mygroup', open:true});
```

Comment: tnx Jack, i'm trying to use your code but as you see i can only show the links as i mentioned above (the js array) :( any solution for that?

Comment: I'm just giving an example.  Take your specific use case and format the example so that it works with it.